# Which one is wordpress cron files to run?

Tags: wordpress, cron

Im trying to find which one is the cron file?, so that I can run it from other server.

But Wordpress has 2 files with name "cron":

1. `wp-cron.php`
2. `wp-includes/cron.php`

Its confusing. Even after searching, Im failed to find discussion about that 2 files.

Answer (score 2):

`wp-cron.php` is the correct one. The one in the `wp-includes` directory is only to be included internally by WP.